# Быстрый поиск значения элемента в массиве

Tags: c++

Вкратце: есть 2D онлайн игра и переменная Item ID, которая занимает 8 байт.
Допустим, один игрок приобретает товар у другого игрока, но на сервер посылает только Item ID товара, который хочет купить. Я тут подумал, а как мне находить кому принадлежит этот самый Item ID. Если я буду сканировать весь список предметов и сравнивать его с этим Item ID, то это занимает слишком много времени, вот несколько идей, которые я подумывал использовать:

1. Использовать цикл по всему массиву предметов (самый тупой метод)
2. Использовать хеш таблицу для хранения Item ID и ее структуры (быстрый метод)
3. Создать Map, где будет храниться, как ключ Item ID, а как вторые данные - указатель на ее структуру

Собственно, у кого есть варианты получше? 
Как мне найти кому принадлежит Item ID если клиент не передает на сервер информацию о том, у кого он покупает товар.

Comment: Для начала используйте 1). Если сервер будет "тормозить" и виновником будет линейный поиск в этом массиве, то переделаете на 2.

Comment: а посылать айди с клиента того, чей товар хочется купить? И все, никаких проблем (ну кроме как проверить, что товар действительно принадлежит тому, кому должен)

Answer (score 0):

используйте бинарный поиск, но для этого нужно чтобы ID были отсортированные